# Drawing complex grid with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with a HTML view using Bootstrap3. I need to create a template with different cells and I usually work with cols and rows, but this time I have a problem with drawing one column.

This is the scheme I need:

[image]
This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 doubleHeight"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9 singleHeight"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 singleHeight"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 singleHeight"></div>
  <!--column bottom right-->
  <!--column bottom left-->
</div>
```

The problem begins when I try to draw the column on the bottom right. If I draw it after the two col-md-3, it doesn't allow me to show the last column on the left inline with it. If I draw it after the last column on the left, it doesn't occupy the space above.
Have you got any idea of the possible solution?
Thanks.

Comment: How does it behave on various screen sizes?

Comment: I just need to use it on md and lg

Comment: I can't immediately think of any way you can do this with default Bootstrap 3,  or even flexbox for that matter.  Is this going to be a scrollable page with content, or is this a full page app that does not scroll?  If you don't have to scroll then positioning things could be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I don't think that bootstrap can span rows like that.

Comment: It will be scrollable!

Comment: Would you be willing to do it without using the bootstrap columns?

Answer (score 3):

**WARNING**: This post contains multiple variations of the same snippet between explanations to demonstrate the logic and provide a visual representation of how the code will actually operate. If you edit it, please keep that in mind.

Before I give you the solution, I want to make something **PERFECTLY** clear, this is **NOT** supported by the Bootstrap framework. To clarify, Bootstrap supports the wrapping of the blocks which can be used to account for this, however, it does **NOT** manipulate the `height` to accommodate a block spanning multiple rows.

Alright, with that said, the closet you can get to your request is via [column wrapping](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping). You can't do multiple layers of blocks because you have blocks that would belong to two different parents, and that simply isn't possible to quantify with the current CSS/HTML structure. Further, you can't do anything for the last block to appear next to the bottom-right block.

Here's a little demo of the structure that gets closet to what you are asking for:

```css
div div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">This block spans one column and unknown rows.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">This block spans three columns and one row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">This block spans one column and row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">This block spans one column and row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">This block spans one column and row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">This block spans three columns and one row.</div>
</div>
```

I added a little `border` to give a visual idea of how it actually renders. Here's the downside to this, it is 100% dependent upon your control of the content in each block to maintain the rows. For example, if you put only enough content in the very first block to account for the height of the second block, you will get the third, fourth, and fifth blocks left flushed and push the sixth block down further.

```css
div div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">One liner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">One liner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">One liner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">One liner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">One liner<br />Two liner</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">One liner</div>
</div>
```

I'm afraid that there is not "easy" way to mitigate this, short of defining `height` for each block. Further, the bottom-right block can **NEVER** exceed the content `height` of the third and fourth blocks. If it exceeds it, then you get a gap between the sixth block and those immediately above it.

```css
div div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    height: 50px;
}

.row-2 {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 row-2">This block spans one column and unknown rows.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">This block spans three columns and one row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">This block spans one column and row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">This block spans one column and row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 row-2">This block spans one column and row.</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">This block spans three columns and one row.</div>
</div>
```

Even though the sixth block fits into the gap, it can only follow the structure if it is after the fifth block. This forces the browser to render it below it. That's `block` for you.

Honestly, the **ONLY** way to make that layout in any framework of HTML(5) and CSS(3) is to use a `table`. It's a **HIGHLY** discouraged practice for layouts, but it, truthfully, is the only option that I know of.

Here's the upside, you can still use the Bootstrap `col-lg-*`, `col-md-*`, `col-sm-*`, and `col-xs-*` classes on the `td`s to ensure they follow the Bootstrap columns sizing.

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">This block spans one column and two rows.</td>
        <td colspan="3">This block spans three columns and one row.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This block spans one column and row.</td>
        <td>This block spans one column and row.</td>
        <td rowspan="2">This block spans one column and two rows.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">This block spans three columns and one row.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm sorry, I know it's not quite what you were looking for, but, at least as far as my knowledge is concerned, it simply isn't possible to do that a wraparound layout without a `table`.

Answer (score 0):

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (javascript) seems ideal for this, although not pure CSS/Bootstrap.

Comment: That only covers rowspan, rather than colspan. It the same thing Bootstrap does, but for rows, and they aren't joinable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the problem was simplified because I had divs with fixed height. I kept Bootstrap template and I assigned to the bottom left div the class of col-md-9, giving it a certain amount of space from the top. I know it's not the best way to do it, but it is horizontally responsive still.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 doubleRow box">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 singleRow box">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 singleRow box">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 singleRow box">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 singleRow box">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 doubleRow box upper">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.singleRow{
    height:280px;
}

.doubleRow{
    height:560px;
    max-height:100%;
}

.upper{
    top: -280px;
    margin-bottom: -280px;  
}

.box {          
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color:black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to make this work so that anyone that wants to do this can see how it can be accomplished? It sounds like the same thing I demo'd in the third snippet of my answer.

Comment: @Stack_kids I see. You used fixed positioning to offset the block. It works for a design with absolute sizing, I suppose, but it has it's flaws. You need to add a `@media` query to prevent the CSS from affecting it in the smaller resolutions. Look at it with a resolution of 991px or less and you should see what I mean.

Comment: I don't have any problem in smaller resolutions because the grid changes in small and extra-small devices... This is the only reason why I could use this solution... Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: By "the grid changes", do you mean that the grid is replaced with something else, or that the Bootstrap appearance changes it? If the latter, the fifth block is completely covered by the sixth at the lower resolutions using the default Bootstrap responsive design. This is because the `.upper` is still being applied to the sixth block. I would imagine that the fixed heights are no longer required in that layout. If it's the former, okay, then just forget I said anything. :)

Comment: I meant that it is replaced with another configuration... (:

Comment: Very well. I just wanted me to make sure we were on the same page. I'm glad you found a solution that works for you. ^^